# ParametricRegion not recognising list of variables

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am trying to use ParametricRegion to plot some parametric equations that can be in various dimensions. The full code is as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Dim = 3;
n = {2,2};
d = Length[n];
T = Table[t[l], {l, 1, d}];
Tmax = 10;

X0 = RandomReal[{-1,1}, Append[n, Dim]];
Colors = RandomReal[{0,1}, Append[n, 3]];

M = Table[0, d];
For[l=1, l<=d, l++,
    col = Table[0, n[[l]]];
    col[[1]] = 1;
    col[[n[[l]]]] = -1;

    row = Table[0, n[[l]]];
    row[[1]] = 1;
    row[[2]] = -1;

    M[[l]] = ToeplitzMatrix[col, row]
];

IndicesToContract = Table[{2*m,2*d+m}, {m, 1, d}];
X = TensorContract[Apply[TensorProduct, Append[Map[MatrixExp, 
MapThread[Times, {-M, T}]], X0]], IndicesToContract];

plots = Table[0, 0];
ParameterSpace = Table[t[l], 0, Tmax}, {l, 1, d}];

idx = Table[1, d];
dim = d;
ready = True;
While[ready,

    x = Extract[X, idx];
    AppendTo[plots, Region[ParametricRegion[x, ParameterSpace]]];

    ready = False;
    While[!ready,
        If[dim > 0,

            If[idx[[dim]] + 1 <= n[[dim]],

                idx[[dim]]++;
                dim = d;
                ready = True,

                idx[[dim]] = 1;
                dim--
                ],

            Break[]
            ]
       ]
];
ParameterSpace
ParametricRegion[x, ParameterSpace]
```

The final line will output something like

```
ParametricRegion[{ ... }, {}]
```

where the last argument should have the list of conditions for the parameters `t[l]` but instead is empty. If I am more explicit and run `ParametricRegion[{ ... }, {{t[1], 0, 10}, {t[2], 0, 10}}]` I do not have this issue. I have tried various ways of running `ParametricRegion` but it always seems to 'forget' what the parameters are unless I enter them manually. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParametricRegion` has `Attribute` [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), so `ParameterSpace` is not evaluated in the second argument, and thus, since the second argument has to be a list, the second argument is invalid and with an invalid second argument

```
ParametricRegion[{a,b}, foo]
```

returns

> ParametricRegion[{a,b}, {}]

You can force evaluation by using

```
ParametricRegion[x, Evaluate @ ParameterSpace]
```

or inject evalauted `ParameterSpace` using function application:

```
ParametricRegion[x, #]& @ ParameterSpace
```

or inject evaluated expression using [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html):

```
With[{ParameterSpace = ParameterSpace}, ParametricRegion[x, ParameterSpace]]

(* or With[{ps = ParameterSpace}, ParametricRegion[x, ps]] *)
```

All three approaches give

> ParametricRegion[{{-0.543429 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 
>          1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) + 
>       0.520054 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) - 
>       0.338647 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) + 
>       0.491181 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])), 
>      0.0504503 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) - 
>       0.937569 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) + 
>       0.227655 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) - 
>       0.98664 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 
>          1/2 E^(-2 t[2])), -0.834933 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 
>          1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) - 
>       0.35056 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) + 
>       0.560079 (1/2 - 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[2])) + 
>       0.997492 (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[1])) (1/2 + 1/2 E^(-2 t[2]))},
>     0 <= t[1] <= 10 && 0 <= t[2] <= 10}, {t[1], t[2]}]